# read bytes in c file (for all line in the file)

Tags: c

I tried to read the bytes in every line of a file.

For one file it worked but it did not work on another file.

```
pFile=fopen(table,"rb");

for (c = 0; c <= 256; c++)
{ 
    fgets (line, sizeof line, pFile); /* read a line */
    sscanf(line,"%d ",&x);
    ranges[c]=x;

    printf ("%d\n",ranges[c]);

}
```

Comment: 1. You open `pFile` and then you read from `fpIn2`, is that intended ? 2. What is the question ?

Comment: sorry .its error you can change fpIn2 to pile

Comment: __You__ can change this by editing your question. And while you're at it, add what the actual problem is. BTW. there is a lot of code missing. Please read this: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *For one file it worked but it did not work on another file.*  Check all return values.  You're ignoring them.  And what does "it did not work" *mean*?  How exactly did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Remove whitespace from the `sscanf` format string.

Comment: i did .... also same problem /// the problem is in one file is ok THE print is ok ,, but in another file noo

Comment: What's the problem in this problem